# Why does imageCapture.takePicture never goes into ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback()'s onImageSaved()?

Tags: java, android, android-camerax

While I was in debugging mode on Android studio I found out the the code doesn't it go into onImageSaved() after iamgeCaputre.takePicture() occured. As if it is telling me that image is not captured and saved at all. It also did not go into onError(). I am programming for Temi Robot for collecting dataset for my custom object detection model.

It will be great if anyone could help to point out the mistake I am having here. Thanks in advance.

**Main Codes**

```
private void setupCameraX() {
    ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture =
            ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);

    cameraProviderFuture.addListener(() -> {
        try {
            ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
            PreviewView previewView = findViewById(R.id.preview_view);
            final Preview preview = new Preview.Builder()
                    .setTargetRotation(Surface.ROTATION_270)
                    .build();
            CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector
                    .Builder()
                    .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT)
                    .build();

            preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.getSurfaceProvider());
            executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

            imageCapture = new ImageCapture
                    .Builder()
                    .setTargetRotation(Surface.ROTATION_270)
                    .setIoExecutor(executor)
                    .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MAXIMIZE_QUALITY)
                    .build();

            cameraProvider.unbindAll();
            cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this,
                    cameraSelector,
                    imageCapture,
                    preview);

            findViewById(R.id.imageCaptureButton).setOnClickListener(v -> {
                this.captureAnImage();
            });
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            new AlertDialog
                    .Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Camera setup error")
                    .setMessage(e.getMessage())
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                            (dialog, which) -> {
                            })
                    .show();
        }
    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));


}

private void captureAnImage() {
    ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions outputFileOptions = new ImageCapture
            .OutputFileOptions
            .Builder(new File("TrainingData"))
            .build();
    imageCapture.takePicture(outputFileOptions,
            executor,
            new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onImageSaved(
                        @NotNull ImageCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
                    Log.d("imagePathname", "Path: " + outputFileResults.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NotNull ImageCaptureException exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.FallDetectionAITrainingCamera">


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.robotemi.sdk.metadata.SKILL"
        android:value="@string/app_name" />

    <activity android:name="org.FallPreventionAITrainingCamera.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**build.gradle**

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "org.FallDetectionAITrainingCamera"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"


}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'

def camerax_version = "1.0.0"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:$camerax_version"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:${camerax_version}"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha26"

implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0"


implementation 'com.robotemi:sdk:0.10.77'
```

}

**Update**
I have tried these codes below but they do not work:

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = (SimpleDateFormat) SimpleDateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
    Date date = new Date();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
            "Fall Prevention Training Data " + formatter.format(date));
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions outputFileOptions = new ImageCapture
            .OutputFileOptions          .Builder(getContentResolver(),MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,contentValues)
            .build();
```

**Update Silly me for not including these logs:**

```
D/CaptureSession: Issuing capture request.
W/LegacyRequestMapper: convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
    Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.  
W/LegacyRequestMapper: convertRequestToMetadata - Ignoring android.lens.focusDistance false, only 0.0f is supported  
E/RequestThread-1: Hit timeout for jpeg callback!  
W/CaptureCollector: Jpeg buffers dropped for request: 1  
E/CameraDevice-JV-1: Lost output buffer reported for frame 116  
W/LegacyRequestMapper: convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
    Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.  
W/LegacyRequestMapper: convertRequestToMetadata - Ignoring android.lens.focusDistance false, only 0.0f is supported  
I/RequestThread-1: Received jpeg.  
W/CaptureCollector: jpegProduced called with no jpeg request on queue!  
E/RequestThread-1: Dropping jpeg frame.
```

**Update**

Upgrading to cameraX1.10-alpha06 did not work.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

 <!-- Register as a system camera app -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
            <action android:name="android.media.action.STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA"/>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.VIDEO_CAMERA" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

I tried `user-feature` and `intent filter` but is doesn't work

Edit:

I guess the main problem here is from the Logs, why does RequestThread-1: Hit timeout for jpeg callback?

Comment: Have you tried passing a real file instead of a random file location?
Try replacing `new File("TrainingData")` with something like this:
`File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "img_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");` and then check if the images are saved in the internal app memory

Comment: Nope, this suggestion did not work. the program never stopped at the break points I put in onImageSaved() or onError()

Comment: You should start removing some customizations, like removing `.setTargetRotation(Surface.ROTATION_270)` everywhere, then trying changing the ImageCapture executor to something like `Executor.newSingleThreadExecutor()` until you see a log in the console or something which tells you where the problem is

Comment: Sure I could experiment with the customisation, also I have finally posted the log. hit timeout for jpeg callback? Yea not familiar with what is going on.

Comment: Try changing capture mode to `.setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)`, By the way if you need help you can find a sample implementation of CameraX here: https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/fragments/CameraFragment.kt

Comment: .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)  
.setTargetRotation()  
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()  

these codes have been changed accordingly but to no avail..

Comment: I suspect the issue is in the device. Does the CameraXBasic app work for you? Could you try and see Camera2Basic works on that device?

Comment: I am no longer working on Temi for know but I believe it is the issue of the device.[I made a clone issue here.](https://github.com/robotemi/sdk/issues/213)
user zjn0505 did ask if my firmware is 20201216.154352 and after i checked, it is. However there is no more replies after that.

Comment: My code taken directly from the android sample for CameraX works on API 29 but fails on 31 and 32.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, hope you find a solution or a workaround soon